# Use Firefox for downloading page (in a password protected site) every 15 minutes

Tags: command-line, password, firefox

I'm logged into a web-site using Firefox (passwords are stored in the password manager). I wish to be able to download a page (not accessible without been logged) every 15 minutes to track certain changing information. The site does not provide any API, and I do not wish to save my password somewhere else.

Is there a command-line argument like `wget <web-page> >> myfile` but `firefox web-page >> myfile`.

Comment: `wget <web-page> --http-user=user --http-password=password >> myfile` much lighter than firefox

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: "I do not wish to save my password somewhere else."

Comment: In addition, `--http-user` and `--http-password` is only useful for HTTP Basic Authentification, not for website-specific cookies.

Comment: @PierreB Is [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/) an option?

Comment: @confetti: I think I'll give Selenium a try first, even if this mean having ot learn a couple of things. iMacros looks good for simple jobs, but it needs a higher Firefox version than the one which is in the Debian repo.

Comment: Nono! Actually, if you have a higher firefox version that would be bad. The new iMacros for firefox quantum has a limited free version. If you have firefox older than FF56 you get to use their old add-on, which is completely free. IIRC, setting up a macro that would download the page content every 15 minutes should be less than 5 lines of code. If it's an option I would look into it for you and offer an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click anywhere on the page and select inspect. Open the network tab of the developer tools, right click on the page, and select copy cURL.

Use Chromium if you want POST data copied for cURL.

Put in a script and add to cron.
The scipt might need to extract a CSRF token or curl the login if the cookie expires.

or if you really want to use the browser you can use https://www.seleniumhq.org/ etc

Comment: Is the copy to cURL supposed to add the cookie data? I've tried it out and it does only include user-agents and some other metadata, but not any login data.

Comment: @confetti: indeed.

Comment: @confetti It includes cookies but I think it doesn't include POST data in some cases. I manually copy the data I need to avoid such issues.

Comment: @user1133275 I see. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

If the web page uses HTTP authentication, you can use wget for that. However, HTTP authentication is rarely used on current web sites.

Now it is most likely that you get a login page the ultimately sets a cookie after login is complete.

- You can try to discover how the login process on your particular site works and emulate that.
- You can login with the browser once, find the right cookies, and then use them with wget to download the content. Normally this should be considered activity that keeps your session from expiring.